# Android Keystore that requires authentication, not unlocked by fingerprint but by pin only?

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-fingerprint-api, key-generator

EDIT: This appears to be device specific.  I have one emulator that this occurs on and one that it works how i'd expect. Would love a universal answer, but maybe there isn't one?

Experiencing something which I think is a little odd.  I've created an AndroidKeyStore that requires user credentials.  Therefore when I try to encrypt using that key, I get the exception "UserNotAuthenticatedException", perfect.

I then launch the confirm device credentials:

```
val keyguardManager = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
        val intent = keyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(("Test"),"This is the description")
        if (intent != null)
            startActivityForResult(intent, AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST)
```

This works perfect, onActivityResult after unlocking with either the PIN or the fingerprint, I get back a success state.  However, when I now try to go and use the keystore again:

If I had used my PIN on the Credentials Screen, I'm able to use the keystore no problem.

If I had used my fingerprint on the Credentials Screen, it throws a "UserNotAuthenticatedException" again.  And I basically can go in an infinite loop with the fingerprint.  Am I missing a setting or something that allows the fingerprint to be used?  I'm able to unlock the phone itself no problem with the fingerprint, its just this keystore that I can't get through.

```
    val keyGenerator =
                    KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore")
                val builder = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                    alias,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
                )
     builder.setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(userAuthenticationRequired)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                        builder.setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(
                            userAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds
                        )
keyGenerator.init(builder.build())
            keyGenerator.generateKey()
```

Thanks

Comment: What device is this?  What you're describing absolutely should work.  I suspect a device-specific bug.

Comment: Ahh yeah forgot to comment on this again.  It did end up being a device specific issue.  I could only recreate it on that specific device, worked as expected on others.  Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a device specific bug.  For whatever reason, the test device I had and was using didn't allow for the fingerprint to unlock it under these circumstances.  It worked as expected with other devices.